# php check if variable isset in the best way

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

can someone told me if it is possible to do this with php **but in a simple syntaxe way** ?

```
$myvar1 = $myvar2 || 'lorem';
```

$myvar2 is not defined (or null) so $myvar1 = 'lorem' else $myvar1 = $myvar2

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myvar1 = isset($myvar2) ? $myvar2 : 'lorem';
```

you need ternary operator

syntax:

```
(expression) ? whenExpIsTrue : whenExpIsFalse;
```

it's equal to:

```
if (isset($myvar2)) {
    $myvar1 = $myvar2;
} else {
    $myvar1 = 'lorem';
}
```

or

```
$myvar1 = 'lorem'; //default value
if (isset($myvar2)) {
    $myvar1 = $myvar2;
}
```

Comment: I thought about downvoting, However I think the question is mis-phrased. 
This is indeed what was asked, I think the question is wrongly worded, but valid.

Comment: It is not equals to `$myvar1 = 'lorem'; if (isset($myvar2)) {  $myvar1 = myvar2; }` because that sets the value first, and the ternary operator does not. You should take that example out.